# youtube-reporting-api retrieve_reports.py "report URL to download"

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

When stepping thru the example python code for creating and retrieving data using the youtube-reporting-api, when I get to the retrieve_report.py code that prompts me to:

Please enter the report URL to download:

What is supposed to be entered here? A specific example would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies, download url's are provided, not sure why it wasn't showing in the first place, maybe copy and pasted the code incorrectly.  It is displayed out of the retrieve_reports function.

It looks like the actual problem is that I did not read the docs thoroughly! reports are not available for 48 hours!

It would be nice if we had a development mode or something, pointing at non-prod youtube environment where we could get reports immediately, am I missing something that could provide this?